# Submit HTTP POST request using LWP::UserAgent giving XML file contents as body

Tags: xml, perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

use FileHandle;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request;

sub printFile($) {

  my $fileHandle = $_[0];

  while (<$fileHandle>) {
    my $line = $_;
    chomp($line);
    print "$line\n";
  }
}

my $message = new FileHandle;

open $message, '<', 'Request.xml' or die "Could not open file\n";
printFile($message);

my $url = qq{https://host:8444};

my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent(ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 0 });

$ua->proxy('http', 'proxy:8080');
$ua->no_proxy('localhost');

my $req = new HTTP::Request(POST => $url);
$req->header('Host' => "host:8444");
$req->content_type("application/xml; charset=utf-8");
$req->content($message);
$req->authorization_basic('TransportUser', 'TransportUser');

my $response = $ua->request($req);
my $content  = $response->decoded_content();
print $content;
```

I am getting the following error.

I want to submit post request using [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP::UserAgent) and I want to give the location of an XML file as the body. I am getting invalid request body error. Request Body is invalid

Comment: Please post the text of your program instead of an image so that we can copy/paste it. You have been told this before in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27456928)

Comment: ok now please check. instead of passing file if I pass content then it's working. But I want to pass xml file

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what `printFile` is for, but you are passing  *file handle* `$message` as the message body, not the contents of the file.

Please take note of the following

- *Always* `use warnings` instead of the `-w` comment line option
- *Never* use subroutine prototypes. `sub printFile($)` should be just `sub printFile`
- There is no need to `use FileHandle` to work with files
- The *reason* for a file `open` failure is in `$!`. You should *always* include it in the `die` string
- Never use the *indirect object* notation. `new LWP::UserAgent` should be `LWP::UserAgent->new`

This version of your code may work a little better, but I have no way of testing it

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP;

my $message = do {
  open my $fh, '<', 'Request.xml' or die "Could not open file: $!";
  local $/;
  <$fh>;
};

my $url = 'https://host:8444';

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 0 });

$ua->proxy(qw/ http proxy:8080 /);
$ua->no_proxy('localhost');

my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $url);
$req->header(Host => 'host:8444');
$req->content_type('application/xml; charset=utf-8');
$req->content($message);
$req->authorization_basic('TransportUser', 'TransportUser');

my $response = $ua->request($req);
my $content  = $response->decoded_content;
print $content;
```